# Reference request: Name or use of this group of diffeomorphisms of the disc

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory

Let $k \in \{0,\infty\}$, $G\subseteq \operatorname{Diff}^k(D^n)$ be the set of diffeomorphisms $\phi:D^n\to D^n$ of the closed $n$-disc $D^n$ (with its boundary) satisfying the following:

- $
  \phi(S_r^{n-1})=S_{r}^{n-1},
  $
  where for every $0\leq r\leq 1$, let $S_r^{n-1}:= \left\{
  x \in D^n:\, \|x\|=r
  \right\}$.

Is $G$ studied?  If so what are some important papers on it?

*It seems like a very intuitive object to be considered.*

Note, when $k=\infty$ this is a subgroup of $\operatorname{Diff}_{\partial}^{\infty}(D^n)$, the group of diffeomorphisms of $D^n$ fixing both the origin and the boundary (well-studied by Hatcher for example).

**Details:**
I'm interested in either extreme, that is $C^{\infty}$ diffeomorphisms of $C^0$ (homeomorphisms).

Comment: *Vague comment:*  It seems like your $
G \cong \sqcup_{0\leq r\leq 1} Diff(S^{n-1})$ or something along those lines.

Comment: Do you mean $C^\infty$-diffeomorphisms? the study of diffeomorphism group**s** of the circle is highly sensitive to the differentiability class.

Comment: I'm most interested in the $C^{\infty}$ or $C^0$ cases, more-so the former.

Comment: It seems that in the $C^\infty$ setting, the elements are (smooth) paths of diffeomorphisms of $S^{n-1}$, such that the endpoint at $0$ is in $O(n)$. In other words, this should be homotopy equivalent to $O(n)$. The reason is that we want $\phi$ to be a diffeo at $0\in D^n$ whose differential preserves the norm. On the other hand, for homeos, there is no boundary condition at $0$ by the Alexander trick.